# Making layers in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns, layer

I have a question that I suspect has a simple answer. I'm using Bootstrap to make a personal webpage, and I'm attempting to divide the background into 3 equal columns (which will all have different images).

I know this could be done with class="col-xs-4" but the issue is that I'd like to keep what's over the background as-is (it's a "col-lg-12" that is responsive).

Is there a way to split my background (again, going to upload images into the 3 panels, and the panels will essentially mask the full images), and still have all the "col-lg-12" heading stuff on top?

Thanks for any help you can give, my current html code is such:

```
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/picture.png" alt="">
                    <div class="intro-text">
                        <span class="intohead">Filler Text</span>
                        <span class="subhead">More detailed, longer filler text for below</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want the final page to look like. You just want `<div class="col-lg-12">...</div>` to have 3 images inside of it?

Comment: No, I'd like it to have a background of 3 columns that I could put images inside (Such as divs where I'd set the images as the background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there are three columns with background images, and then a cover `div` that is placed on top of the three columns. You can place anything you like in the cover `div`. Here's an article about [CSS positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
}
.section {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 33.33333%;
}
.one {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x300/ccc/666/&text=img+1) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.two {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x300/666/ccc/&text=img+2) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.three {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x300/ccc/666/&text=img+3) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*A background isn't needed, it's just to show that the element is there*/
  background: salmon;
  opacity: .5;
  /* this stuff is key */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* place cover on top */
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cover">Put all you content in here</div>
  <div class="section one"></div>
  <div class="section two"></div>
  <div class="section three"></div>
</div>
```

Run the code snippet and tell me what happens. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the background I want, but I can do that with 3 of bootstrap's "col-xs-4" (as I mentioned in my question, I'm using bootstrap). The issue is putting the "col-lg-12" div over that, with it's own responsive image, text, etc. I can't make them be one over another in the same row.

Comment: Ok, so to put one `div` over another, use `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` on the cover to place it directly on top. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey 773 I'm actually still having an issue. Thanks again for your help though. The header itself has the background color, and everything else is floating on top of it. So I put the 3 section divs right after the header tag, and added the "cover" class to the container div. But, just adding absolute (even without left) causes everything to shift left when it was all responsively centered before.

Comment: Hey 773, I got it to work by adding "left: 0; right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" to the CSS for cover, in addition to what you have. Thanks for the help!